# Why tungsten does not have stable configuration?

Tags: electronic-configuration, transition-metals

Whenever there are 4 unpaired electrons in d-orbital, elements try to attain stable electronic configuration. For example copper.

Electronic configuration of copper should be [Ar]3d<sup>4</sup> 4s<sup>2</sup>, but it tries to attain stable state and so it changes to [Ar]3d<sup>5</sup> 4s<sup>1</sup>.

I have seen it happens with most of the elements but not with tungsten. Electronic configuration of tungsten is [Xe]4f<sup>14</sup> 5d<sup>4</sup>  6s<sup>2</sup> and not [Xe]4f<sup>14</sup> 5d<sup>5</sup>  6s<sup>1</sup>(more stable).

What is the reason behind that?

Comment: If it was more stable, it would be adopted, so it isn't more stable. Anyway, the electronic configurations of the transition metals are often quite hard to rationalise, there are many factors that will tip the balance in favour of one configuration or another.

Comment: @orthocresol yeah that was my question why 5d4 is more stable then 5d5. Can you sate few factors that... I think you can add it as answer.

Comment: @jan not really. There is no where mention of tungsten configuration (at one place there is but that is not what I am asking,right?)

Comment: The basis of that question tells you that the electron configuration you termed ‘stable’ is, in fact, ‘abnormal’. So tungsten actually assumes the *normal* configuration. Thus, I consider it a duplicate.

Comment: @Freddy Aesin's answer does give some mention to tungsten at the end. In general, the principles behind the effect are given in the linked question so the same answer applies here.