# Why do tungsten and chromium have different electronic configurations?

Tags: electronic-configuration

Why is the outer structure of tungsten $\mathrm{5d^46s^2}$ instead of $\mathrm{5d^56s^1}$?

I try to explain this in comparison  with outer structure  of chromium $\mathrm{4d^55s^1}$  taking into consideration  5d orbitals have lesser energy than 6s orbitals in tungsten by saying that the size of the energy gap between the 3d and 4s orbitals lesser than size of the energy gap between the 5d and 6s orbitals, and the repulsion between electrons in the structure$\mathrm{5d^46s^2}$  more than  the repulsion  in the structure $\mathrm{5d^56s^1}$ which can push the electron from 5d to 6s to produce the lowest energy structure.

I need qualitative answer?

Comment: also https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/41304/why-tungsten-does-not-have-stable-configuration

Comment: Cr is 3d5 4s1, not 4d5 5s1.

Comment: @orthocresol thank you i  edit and  correct  the structure of Cr.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly note that the energetic differences between $\mathrm d^m\mathrm s^n$ and $\mathrm d^{m-1}\mathrm s^{n+1}$ configurations are generally not large. Sometimes these are not amenable to simple qualitative rationalisation.

However in this case it is possible to argue along two lines.

1. Relativistic effects lead to the stabilisation of the 6s subshell and destabilisation of the 5d subshell, which directly favours population of 6s over 5d.
2. Electron-electron repulsions in the 3d/4s orbitals are generally larger than repulsions in the 5d/6s orbitals, because the latter are more diffuse. Hence chromium chooses to adopt a configuration in which exchange energy is maximised (i.e. electron-electron repulsions are minimised).

Comment: The energetic differences between 3d and 4s  lesser  or larger than  energetic differences between 5d and 6s   ?

Comment: Electron-electron repulsions in the$\mathrm{5d^46s^2}$ structure are larger  or  lesser than repulsions in the $\mathrm{5d^56s^1}$ structure?